# What, exactly, does a modelbinder do? How to use it effectively?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, annotations, model-binding

I was researching something and came across [this blog post at buildstarted.com](http://buildstarted.com/2010/09/12/custom-model-binders-in-mvc-3-with-imodelbinder/) about model binders.  It actually works pretty darn well for my purposes but I am not sure exactly whats going on behind the scenes.  What I did was create a custom ModelBinder called `USerModelBinder`:

```
public class UserModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        ValueProviderResult value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("id");
        MyEntities db = new MyEntities();
        User user = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == value.AttemptedValue);
        return user;
    }
}
```

Then in my `Global.asax.cs` I have:

`ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(User), new UserModelBinder());`

My understanding is that using the model binder allows me to NOT have to use the following lines in every controller action that involves a "User".  So instead of passing in an "id" to the action, the modelbinder intercepts the id, fetches the correct "item"(User in my case) and forwards it to the action for processing.

```
        MyEntities db = new MyEntities();
        User user = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == value.AttemptedValue);
```

I also tried using an annotation on my User class instead of using the line in Global.asax.cs:

```
[ModelBinder(typeof(UserModelBinder))]
public partial class User
{
}
```

I'm not looking for a 30 page white paper but I have no idea how the model binder does what it does.  I just want to understand what happens from when a request is made to the time it is served.  All this stuff "just working" is not acceptable to me, lol.  Also, is there any difference between using the annotation versus adding it in Global.asax.cs?  They seem to work the same in my testing but are there any gotchas?

Comment: Have you come across [these](http://www.chrispfarrell.com/Blog/MVCRoutingandtheModelBinder) [articles](http://blogs.charteris.com/blogs/gopalk/archive/2009/02/11/how-does-asp-net-mvc-work-part-2.aspx)? They seem to go quite in-depth as to how it all works.

Comment: The one negative you may want to consider is that you are giving up the ability to modify your query to retrieve as much information as you require as possible.  This is a big deal if you're using an ORM with lazy loading since it's worth writing a query that forces loading of things you know you'll need rather then letting the lazy loading mechanism load them in a separate query later.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Usually the Model Binder (in MVC) looks at you Action method and sees what it requires (as in, the objects types). It then tries to find the values from the HTTP Request (values in the HTTP Form, QueryString, Json and maybe other places such as cookies etc. using ValueProviders). It then creates a new object with the parameters that it retrieves.

IMO What you've done is not really "model binding". In the sense that you've just read the id and fetched the object from the DB.

example of usual model binding:

```
// class
public class SomeClass
{
    public int PropA {get;set;}
    public string PropB {get;set;}
}

// action

public ActionResult AddSomeClass(SomeClass classToBind)
{
  // implementation
}

// pseudo html

      <form action="">
       <input name="PropA" type="text" />
       <input name="PropB" type="text" />
      </form>
```

if you post a form that contains the correct values (lets say you post a form with PropA and PropB ) the model binder can identify that you've sent those values in the form and build a SomeClass object.

If you really want to create a real working example  you should use a strongly typed View and use HtmlHelper's EditorFor (or EditorForModel) to create all the correct names that MVC needs.

--

for reference MVC's default binder is the [DefaultModelBinder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.defaultmodelbinder.aspx), and some (there are more, you can look around in the System.Web.Mvc namespace) ValueProviders that it uses by default are the [FormValueProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.formvalueprovider.aspx) and the [QueryStringValueProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.querystringvalueprovider.aspx)

So, as I already said, how this basically works is that the default model binder reads the model that the action is recieving (say SomeClass in the example) reads what are the values that it can read (say PropA and PropB) and asks the ValueProviders for the correct values for the properties.

Also, if I recall correctly, you can also see the value providers in runtime using the ValueProviderFactories static class.

Comment: What else could I do to make it "really model binding"?  I was just playing around with but what other functions would the modelbinder perform?

Answer (score 3):

A `ModelBinder` looks at the arguments of the selected `Controller` action's method signature, then converts the values from the `ValueProvider`s into those arguments.

This happens when the `ControllerActionInvoker` invokes the action associated with the `ControllerContext`, because the `Controller`'s `Execute()` method told it to.

For more about the ASP.NET MVC execution process, see [Understanding the MVC Application Execution Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381612.aspx)